# Wrong focus area of form elements in android 4 (ICS) WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, right-to-left

I have a form in a **Right To Left** html page and I have a `WebView` that shows it. Html input fields of my page can't get focus when I tap exactly on them but when I try tapping somewhere beside of correct area, it becomes focused.
My issue occurs just when the phone is in portrait mode, while I don't face it in landscape mode.

Here are screenshots of aforementioned issue:
[image: portrait mode]
[image: landscape mode]
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem caused by adding **dir** attribute with **rtl** value to **html** or **body** tag.
Your **html** or **body** should not have this:

```
dir="rtl"
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the W3C spec, http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html the dir attribute can be added to the html element, so I'm not sure that's it

> To set the base text direction for an entire document, set the dir attribute on the HTML element.

I am also seeing some odd issues with the RTL behavior with Android browsers (it works fine on a desktop).

Comment: When I add dir="rtl" attribute to html tag, it happens. You can do same thing to be sure about how my problem occurs. So if according to the W3C spec, dir attribute can be added to the html tag, it's an ICS WebView bug. Also it's not about dir attribute on html tag, it's just about dir with "rtl" value on html tag.

Comment: I'm wasn't saying that there isn't a bug with Android. I was responding to the comment about the fact that it was not correct to put the dir attribute on the html element, this is a perfectly correct place to put it. I have also seen exactly the same issue as you with regard to the offset position of "click zones" I have put this down to a bug in Android which is triggered by the RTL setting. Where the setting is appears to be irrelevant.